# Excel VBA - Incremental Check and Merge

Tags: excel, merge, vba

OK so here I go with my first question, advance apologies for any ambiguities.

I am working on a sheet where I pull data through SQL, and copy it to a certain table. The data contains string value. I am currently using vba to pull data (as there are variable involved), and copy it to grid how I want it.

The problem comes here; after I have copied the data, I have to merge certain Cells (sometimes two sometimes 3), and I do this manually. The condition is if C13 = C14 then merge, and if I merge C13 and C14 I have to merge B13 and B14 as well, and D13 and D14 as well. Next I want to check if the merged cell (which is now C13) is equal to C15, and then merge C13 to C15, and if this condition is true then B & D are also going to be merged.

If the condition of C13 is not true i.e. C13 <> C14 I want to go to next cell C14 and check if C14 = C15 or not.

I want to do this with vba, but trying to do this manually, will run into miles and miles of codes can someone please help?

This is the start of the code I have found here and managed to change a bit but now I am lost

```
Sub Merge()
    Dim k As Range, cell As Range, name As String
    Set k = Range("C13:C50")
    For Each cell In k
        If cell.Value =

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could propose you the following code:

```
Sub Merge()
    Dim k As Range, cell As Range, name As String
    Set k = Range("C13:C50")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do_it_again:
    For Each cell In k
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value _
            And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            Debug.Print cell.Address
            'for column C
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            'for column B
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(cell.MergeArea.Rows.Count, 1).Merge
            'for column D
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(cell.MergeArea.Rows.Count, 1).Merge
            GoTo Do_it_again
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I don't necessary like the code I proposed but after all it works as presented below.

[image]

**Edit to improve efficiency** 
I have to admit that previous code wasn't efficient for big data table, like 5000 rows or more. One below is 90% faster but still need approx 10-20 sec for 5000 rows of data.

Most important changes compared to the code above are marked *****.

```
Sub Merge()
    Dim k As Range, cell As Range, name As String
    Dim kStart As Range, kEnd As Range '*****
        Set kStart = Range("C13")      '*****
        Set kEnd = Range("C8000")      '*****

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False       '*****
Do_it_again:
    For Each cell In Range(kStart, kEnd)     '*****
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value _
            And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            Application.StatusBar = cell.Address  '***** check progress in Excel status bar

            'for column C
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            'for column B
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(cell.MergeArea.Rows.Count, 1).Merge
            'for column D
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(cell.MergeArea.Rows.Count, 1).Merge
            Set kStart = cell      '*****
            GoTo Do_it_again
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True      '*****
End Sub
```

Comment: I have been testing this code, it works perfectly well, until I come across a situation, when there are 4 or 5 cells to be merged i.e. it merges two and two, rather than merging the whole. Have been trying to tweak the code unsuccessfully :( help again pleas

Comment: Can you upload data screen shot or data file to see structure of data making a problem...

Comment: It's obvious if you run this code for lots, lots of rows. Test it for 20 rows, if it works be patient ;)

Comment: actually it became unresponsive for 3 cells, but I am going to try and run it again for a bigger file.

Comment: The code is unresponsive to the point, that I cannot use it :( sorry dude

Comment: hmmm on a second thought, thats is the only bug there, I am going to work it over the weekend and try to sort out the un-limited  cyclic issue

Comment: which long is your `k range` in your sample? for my 1000 rows long example proposed code works in half second, without any problems.

Comment: k starts with C13 and ends at C50 (max) for some reason it is going in an endless cycle, I am not sure why, have been trying various combinations without luck.

Comment: I would need to see real data you work with to try to help you more. Screen shot or uploaded file.....

Comment: Let me see what I can do here,

Comment: It was important to see your data which allows me to provide new improved code. Pleas, find it in my answer. What is important? I've changed the way you define your range- now you set starting and ending points separately.

Comment: I think there is a problem with my sheet, coz the code works perfectly when I run it from another file, but when I place it in my file, it acts wierd

Comment: if you need any support you need to tell more about your problem.

Comment: I made a new sheet incorporating the code you created, and it solved the problem. There was a problem with the code itself. Thanks Kaz for your help, is there a way I can learn the part of looping in vba?

Comment: you're welcome... you could try [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/ff458124#VBAstart) or more deeply-[this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211382%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks man, I have took the code further and added another column to the merge list, and it is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, forgot to initialize count @ 14

```
current = cells(13,3)
count = 14
for i = 14 to 15
next = cells(i,3)
If current = next then
    'match encountered, merge columns B,C,D
    for j = 2 to 4
        cells(13,j) = cells(13,j) & cells(count,j)
    next j
    count = count + 1
end if
next i
```

If you are not trying to append but replace the value of C13 with C14 if matched, and C13 with C15 if matched etc..., then change the line

```
cells(13,j) = cells(13,j) & cells(count,j)
```

to

```
cells(13,j) = cells(count,j)
```

Comment: The condition for merge is that, the (C13,C14,C15, and so on) should be equal. It may be that C13 = C14 OR C13 = C14 = C15 OR C13 = C14 = C15 = C16 OR C13 = C14 = C15 = C16 = C17 OR even C13 = C14 = C15 = C16 = C17 = C18